# Calling asmx service from .net core api2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

i need to call an old asmx web service (I have not control over)from a .net core web api

is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I was able to do it was fully update Visual Studio 2017, then get the latest WCF Connected Services extension from here: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WCFCORETEAM.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService

After I did that, I was able to add and call the SOAP service like so.
Right click on **Connected Services** folder (should appear just below your project) and select **Add Connected Service**. Then select "Add a WCF web service". Put your asmx url into the URI field, set the name space and click Finish. You will now have the reference set.
An example of what my code does...
If you don't have an authorization header, you can ignore that part:

```
MySoapClient.EndpointConfiguration endpoint = new MySoapClient.EndpointConfiguration();  
MySoapClient myService = new MySoapClient(endpoint, myURL);              
AuthorizationSoapHeader MyAuthHeader = new AuthorizationSoapHeader();

MyAuthHeader.AppName = FDSServiceAppName;
MyAuthHeader.AppID = Guid.Parse(MyAppID); 

Entry[] entries = MyService.GetUsers().Result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,just seen this .I have used the Visual studio WCF connected services but wondered if there is a way  of doing it without generating all that code and just use channels directly

Comment: You're welcome. My previous approach was as follows.(I am not sure of any additional routes to go). Since my Core project targeted .Net Framework 4.6.1, I created an additional project (a class project also targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1). From there I was able to add a Web Reference the way one could in the past. Within this project I created a class with a publicly accessible method that calls the asmx service. Then, within my MVC Core project, I set a reference to this additional project and was able to call the public method on the other project.

Comment: Link/Extension is dead, I am using visual studio 2017 15.9.2

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is 100% correct, but there was one gotcha when trying to add an ASMX Web Service with VS WCF Connected Services that I encountered, but wasn't initially obvious to me.

In my case the web service that I was trying to connect to had disabled the WSDL in the Web.config.  I had to remove or comment out the following in the Web.config to allow the metadata to be imported and code scaffolded successfully.

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <!-- <remove name="Documentation" /> -->
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Once `<remove name="Documentation" />` is removed or commented out like the example above, the ASMX service will be able to be added to your project.